# Bash SED Unterminated `s' command

Tags: bash, sed

I am a newbie at Bash scripting and have ran into a problem. I have searched and it looks like the issue may be the contents of my variable $MODIFIED.

Was wondering if anybody could help me find a way around this?

I am trying to fetch the last 5 modified files from a directory and then import them into a second script by replacing the first line in the second script.

My code so far:

```
#Pipe last 5 modified files within Students and output to script2
#Checks if script2 exists to avoid overwriting.
cd ~/Students/Stu5
MODIFIED=$(ls -1t | head -5)


if [ -f ~/Documents/OSShellScripts/OSScript2.sh ]; then
        cd ~/Documents/OSShellScripts
        echo "OSScript2 already exists."
        sed -i "1s/.*/$MODIFIED/" ~/Documents/OSShellScripts/OSScript2.sh
fi
```

This returns the error: sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command

If i change the MODIFIED variable to say "hello" it works perfectly.

Any help with pointing me where I am going wrong would be great, thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to clarify some things. `bash` is a shell. A shell runs programs, that's its purpose. `sed` is a stream editor, and is NOT part of bash, it's a separate program .. which you could run from bash, sh, csh, zsh, fish, or directly from some other program. There is no such thing as "bash sed". What you've got is the sed program being run by a bash script. If you need help with the sed command, that's not a bash issue.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, sorry about the poor terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly properly quote bash variable when passing to sed.

Secondly remember that You are passing array into sed.

If that's on purpose You would need to do something like this:

```
sed -i '1s/.*/'"$(echo ${MODIFIED})"'/' ~/Documents/OSShellScripts/OSScript2.sh
```

I would also change sed's substitute command `s` to change line command `c`, since your variable may contain slashes:

```
sed -i '1c\'"$(echo ${MODIFIED[@]})"
```

Comment: Always quote your variable - `echo "$x"`, not `echo $x`.

Comment: Thanks but here is already quoted "$(echo ${x})" because of passing to sed, you can't quote again inside

Comment: @Kubator Yes, you can (and should) quote within command substitution. One of the advantages of `$()` over backticks is that you don't have to escape quotes, it creates a new quoting scope.

Comment: I am interested in this one, could you provide example with sed passing for instance? Because here if You quote like sed '1c\'"$(echo "${MODIFIED}")" sed will fail with expression error